# Injecting DOM elements AngularJS using Directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<ul>` as such with `<li>`'s:

```
    <li ng-repeat="x in xs" ng-class-odd="'x'" ng-class-even="'y'">
    // inject here
        <span>
            {{x.v}}
        </span>
    </li>
```

I'd like on a certain event to inject a context menu (DOM position described above) that looks like this:

```
        <ul id="context" class="col">
            <li class="three"><span>1</span></li>
            <li class="three"><span>2</span></li>
            <li class="three"><span>3</span></li>
        </ul>
```

What's the best way to implement this? 1, 2 and 3 above have the same functions to handle the repeated list items in the parent container. So I'm not sure if injecting the context menu as described above is a smart idea since It would generate unseeded repetitions of the context menu.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't be hard to have a contextmenu directive inserted in body that listens for $rootscope broadcast of mouse location and item `x`. Bind another directive to your repeating elements that has the `contextmenu` event handler in it and does the broadcast

Comment: @charlietfl can you please show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a contextmenu directive that is already available open source or you could just create one on your own. check this out https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-context-menu, https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngContextMenu

Comment: Hi thanks, this looks great. However, i'd like to inject the partial using hammer-swipe instead of right clicking...

Comment: Here: body.bind('click', function onClick() {

                        // Remove all of the open context menus.
                        scope.$apply(contextMenu.cancelAll);

                    }); Can i edit this to make it work with `hm-swipe` instead of click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really basic example of a set of contextmenu directives where menu is inserted once in body.

One directive is used to bind the `contenxtmenu` event and send data to the directive that controls the menu itself.

The item selected and the mouse position get passed as data in the broadcast

HTML

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" context="item">{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul menu id="context" ng-show="menu_on">
    <li ng-click="itemAlert('id')">Alert ID</li>
    <li ng-click="itemAlert('title')">Alert Title</li>
  </ul>
```

JS

```
app.directive('context', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      item: '=context'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('contextmenu', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var data = {
          pos: { x: evt.clientX, y: evt.clientY},
          item: scope.item
        }
        scope.$apply(function(){
          $rootScope.$broadcast('menu', data);
        });

      });
    }
  }
})

 app.directive('menu', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.$on('menu', function(evt, data) {
        scope.menu_on = true;
        scope.item = data.item;
        var cssObj = {
          left: data.pos.x + 20 + 'px',
          top: data.pos.y - 40 + 'px'
        };
        elem.css(cssObj)
      });
      scope.itemAlert = function(prop) {
        scope.menu_on = false;
        alert(scope.item[prop])
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Would need some additional document listeners to close menu when user clicks outside of it. Objective here was to just create basic mechanics of being able to display menu and pass data.

I haven't looked but there are probably some open source directives already available that are far more advanced than this.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHAbYTlO4JpysOLytahR?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: amazing answer.. I am giving it a try, but please note that I am not activating the contextmenu with right-click but with Hammer.js swipe event. How can this be adapted?

Comment: Don't know hammer but if it binds event handlers to elements would be same principle as the way I used 'bind'

Comment: Doesn't answer the question directly, but put me on the right track to complete the directive. Thanks!